# Android SMS confirmation dialog

Tags: android, documentation, sms, confirmation

Can anyone tell me where to find documentation about confirmation dialog shown on the image below? I would like to properly handle case when user taps "Cancel".

Current [android SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) documentation does not describe this dialog. By performing empirical tests, I found out that when you tap cancel, result code is some constant value `0x5`.

Dialog shows following info: "[APP-NAME] would like to send a message to [PHONE-NUMBER]". I don't know when this dialog was introduced in Android, but it is shown on both Nexus (4.2.1) and S3 (4.2.2).

[image: Confirmation dialog]

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you find anything?????

Comment: Nope. Only the magic `0x5` constant. So far, it has been battle tested.

Comment: have you found any solution for that? i am also facing that problem.

Comment: Any progress? Found the same with Galaxy S3